# Formula that counts every 9th row

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, modular-arithmetic

I need a formula that counts every 9th row in the D column starting with D209. So far I have:

```
=sumif(ArrayFormula(mod((row(D1:D)-row(D1)+1),9)),0,D1:D)
```

The formula works right by counting every 9th row but I'm having a hard time getting the formula to start at D209.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=ArrayFormula(sumif(mod((row(D209:D)-row(D209)+1),9),0,D209:D))+D209
```

The intent of `+1` and `+D209` is to count, but not double count, the value in that cell<sup>†</sup>. There may be other (and better!) ways to achieve the same result but I aimed to minimise the difference between the formula above and the OP's attempt (except I moved `ArrayFormula` to the outside as that may be better practice in general). Minimising differences can help OPs to understand what it was they got wrong (though I admit the reason here was me being lazy, as usual).

<sup>†</sup> [Off-by-one error](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) may be of interest. Whereas the indices of "every 9th" would mostly be multiples of `9` the *first* entry would be index `1` (1-based), as I understand the requirement.

Comment: Do you need the +1? I think =ArrayFormula(sumif(mod((row(D209:D)-row(D209)),9),0,D209:D))  would be enough?